# Unable to Launch Android SDK Manager

Tags: android

I am unable to launch android sdk manager, I have checked sdk, jdk path properly but unable to resolve this . While I am starting Android SDK manager in eclipse consol shows these lines:

```
 [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(SAXParserFactory.java:419)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.getParser(DeviceParser.java:370)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceParser.parse(DeviceParser.java:355)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.loadDevices(DeviceManager.java:419)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getVendorDevices(DeviceManager.java:215)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevices(DeviceManager.java:167)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDevice(DeviceManager.java:147)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getDeviceStatus(DeviceManager.java:136)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1413)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1325)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:286)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:296)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:266)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:123)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:87)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:339)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:308)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
    [2014-02-19 14:46:44 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Comment: Is it for the first time that you are launching it?

Comment: Try to check where is your path ANDROID_HOME set

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: not first, i used it since a year facing problem while i was installing plugins of phonegap my system was shotdown and since sdk manager not started yet

Comment: @user974801 ya setted

Answer (score 0):

Try with a newer **ADT** version which is provided by Google. It will help you